# Allowing touch to pass through transparent images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using a piece of code I found to pass touch events through transparent parts of a `UIImageView`. I'm subclassing `UIImageView` and adding this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    unsigned char pixel[1] = {0};
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 
                                                 1, 1, 8, 1, NULL,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-point.x, -point.y)];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGFloat alpha = pixel[0]/255.0;
    BOOL transparent = alpha < 0.01;
    if(transparent){
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

So far its working great in my iPad version. However, in my iPhone version, I set the image frames to be half of the image's actual size (`self.image.frame.size.width/2`). This code is interfering with my pan gestures in an odd way, where if I touch the top left of the image I cannot access my pan gesture, but I can access it to the far bottom right, past the actual image into a transparent zone.

Removing the code returns the pan gesture to normal. However, I would still like to keep the ability to ignore touches on transparent parts. Does anyone know what part of this code is messing with my touch points or any other reason its acting like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I just had to use this on a project and my problem was that I was setting the imageView frame manually. What helped was changing the code so resizing was only done through transforms.

If the imageView is initially the same size as the image inside it, you can use this code and it will work with any transform applied to the imageView afterwards.

So in your iPhone version, you could set the frame of the imageView to the size of the image inside it and then apply a scaling transform to it so it's half the size.